# TideKit free version for students / opensource

Tags: tidekit

Will you plan to release a free version of TideKit for students/education or open source projects?

https://www.tidekit.com/reservations

Comment: "You" as in "the Stackoverflow audience"? Otherwise, this is the wrong forum...

Comment: I writed here because in the footer of the website is the link: [Community Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tidekit).

And was there question non-programming like this: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800197/is-tidekit-still-in-progress), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26094684/tidekit-expected-release).

Because I writed here.

Comment: TideKit does not exist any more. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28204167/3737186)